# Сохранение картинки с оригинальным именем laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, изображения

У меня есть форма в которой есть поле `<input type="file" name="images[]" multiple="">` сохраняю я картинки в модельки вот таким вот способом `$image->store('upload', 'public');` только вот проблема картинку загружаю с названием 123412321.jpg а сохраняется она с таким названием A9mwuXwMCGkkag5xPSBJMl8JxzvNrt6YwkfAYssj.jpeg как сохранять с оригинальным именем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример сохранение оригинального имени файла

```php
$image = $request->file('image');
$originalname = $image->getClientOriginalName();
$path = $file->storeAs('public/', $originalname);
```